# Git Push with Atom - Not working

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

When I try to push it gives this message:

```
/tmp/github-11836-9666-1bhip27.i6pr/git-credential-atom.sh get: 1: /tmp/github-11836-9666-1bhip27.i6pr/git-credential-atom.sh get: /tmp/github-11836-9666-1bhip27.i6pr/git-credential-atom.sh: Permission denied

fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/github-11836-9666-1bhip27.i6pr/git-askpass-atom.sh': Permission denied

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I saw a video, and when the guy try to pus, Atom ask for username and password. My Atom doesnt do that. If I try to push through Linux Terminal I get it easely with `git push`. How do I fix that?

Comment: Seems like you don't have permissions to run the scripts. You could try if running atom with `sudo` solves your problem. This is a bad solution and you should probably change permissions instead!

Comment: I tryed 'sudo atom' and I still get the error.

Comment: Permission won’t be fixed with sudo. You need permission from the github repo owner.

Comment: I am the owner, how do I do that